# Construct Generic class without knowing type

Tags: c#, generics

i would like to construct a generic class with generic parameters without knowing the type.

```
List<T> genericList = new List<T>();

public void AddGenericValue<T>(T t1, T t2)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < genericList.Count; i++)
    {
        if (genericList[i].t1 == t1)
        {
            genericList[i].t2 = t2;
            return;

        }
    }

    genericList.Add(new GenericClass(t1, t2));
}

public class GenericClass<T>
{
    T t1;
    T t2;

    public GenericClass(T t1, T t2)
    {
        this.t1 = t1;
        this.t2 = t2;
    }
}
```

Now i get error Using the generic type 'GenericClass' requires 1 type of argument.

Comment: First your list is of type `T`, not `GenericClass`. Thus `genericLis.Add(new ...)` dwon´t compile. Second you have to provide the generic parameter to the constructor: `new GenericClass<T>(t1, t2)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the generic parameters when stating the type:

```
new GenericClass<T>(t1, t2)
```

The reason for this is that type parameters cannot be inferred for classes, only for methods. You can make use of this by writing a factory:

```
static class GenericClassFactory
{
  public static GenericClass<T> Create(T t1, T t2)
  {
    return new GenericClass<T>(t1, t2);
  }
}
```

Now you can:

```
var foo = GenericClassFactory.Create(1, 2);
```

And `T` will be deduced by the compiler.

Also, the list should be a the right type:

```
var genericList = new List<GenericClass<T>>();
```

If you need to store the list as a member variable then you'll need to promote the generic type to the class level rather than the method level:

```
class Foo<T>
{
    private readonly List<GenericClass<T>> genericList = new List<GenericClass<T>>();

    public void AddGenericValue(T t1, T t2)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < genericList.Count; i++)
        {
            if (genericList[i].t1 == t1)
            {
                genericList[i].t2 = t2;
                return;

            }
        }

        genericList.Add(new GenericClass<T>(t1, t2));
    }
}
```

Comment: Cheers mate, it works. But if i would like to move the list outside the method? How can i achive that? Since then T will not be defined

Comment: @Printer You can either move the `T` onto the class (rather than the method), declare the list as `List<object>` and then deal with casting or define an interface (eg `IGenericClass`) and have `T` implement it and make the list `List<IGenericClass>`

Comment: I'm bit lost, can you provide me any example of the interface solution?

Comment: @Printer - It would help if you edit the question to explain how you want to use the list.

Comment: Sorry, i've updated the question. How can i make it work with that setup? Thanks for taking your time, appreciate it

Comment: This works great, is it possible to avoid make whole class to generic? Maybe i should move this to a own class? Or is it another way?

Comment: @Printer - As you're accessing data in the generic class you''ll need to make your class generic.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the enlightenment. I should fiddle by my own and see how i can make it work with my setup. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

This may fix your issue:

```
List<GenericClass<T>> genericList = new List<GenericClass<T>>();
genericList.Add(new GenericClass<T>(t1, t2));
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things you need here,

1. Your instance of class should expect generic parameter i.e `<T>`, so create instance of `GenericClass`like

   ```
     new GenericClass<T>(t1, t2)
   ```
2. To avoid compile time error define your List properly

   ```
     List<GenericClass<T>> genericList = new List<GenericClass<T>>();
   ```